# SO reputation score just plummeted?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, score

Can anyone explain why my SO reputation just plummeted from just over 2,000 to 1,200? (User: ILMV).

- I started with 1,997 points
- Answered a question
- Edited my answer a couple times
- Received a up vote to put me to 2,007
- Now I have 1,207 ?

Can anyone explain this?

Also if this is in the wrong area please move :-)

**Edit**

After Toms answer, is there a mod that can check if my score has been recalculated. Thanks :-)

Comment: "...is there a mod that can..." Already done; refresh screen ;-p

Answer (score 8):

There is no "recalc" in your log (all such are fully logged), so I don't think it was this. I presume, then, another account (perhaps well-meaning) had up-voted your account so heavily and exclusively that it was seen as suspicious (automatically) and the votes cancelled.

This happens occasionally (very rarely), as an unfortunate side-effect of having a fanboy. Sorry 'bout that, but I suppose you should be flattered?

Comment: Which reminds me, we need to add a user history record when that happens.

Comment: @Jeff - I'm surprised you don't do that already.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure id I'm flattered really, but nevermind. Cheers for the response.

Answer (score 4):

There's a thing called a rep recalc.  It recalculates your Reputation, so deleted questions/answers, and fradulent votes don't count for or against you.  Most people lose rep from a recalc - I just did it to myself on Meta and went from 3,975 to 3,859.

A SO mod might be able to see if your Rep got recalced - it can be triggered manually, or automatically by fraud algorithms, Account Mergers, and some other misc. things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tom, much appreciated :-).

Comment: It wasn't an explicit recalc - log says "no".

Answer (score 0):

Your [reputation graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80111?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top) says that you've never been above 1200.  Not sure what that means if you really did have a score of 2000, but it is interesting, nonetheless.

Comment: That probably indicates suspicious voting pattern removals, then.

Comment: Well this sucks... I can't think why out of my relatively small reputation I could get 800 points via spammers. It would have been good if there was a definitive reason / log as to why this has happened.